# Matlab: geoshow's grid and frame

Tags: matlab

I'm currently trying to plot a map from a .shp file and the result is not aesthetically pleasing:

```
minx=-75;
maxx=-68;
miny=-40;
maxy=-30;
cntry02=shaperead('cntry02', 'UseGeoCoords', true);

figure
geoshow(cntry02, 'FaceColor', [1 1 1]);
axis([minx-1 maxx+1 miny-1 maxy+1])
grid on
```

which produces 
[image: rubish]

Is there a way to

1) plot all the grid (over the countries)?

2) plot the entire frame?

3) display S and W, instead of negative values of latitude and longitude?

I've been fighting with this problem all the morning. Thanks in advance.

You can download the .shp file from here. 
http://openmap.bbn.com/svn/openmap/trunk/share/data/shape/cntry02/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problem 1 and2, the reason is that the axes are always behind the plot. So one solution is to add new axes on the current one and display grid, box, and customized ticks.

For problem 3, I use `regexprep` to replace negative latitude with S suffix (idem for longitude). The only problem I have is that longitude 0 will be 0E, and latitude 0, 0N.

And here is the code:

```
figure;
axes;
geoshow(cntry02, 'FaceColor', [1 1 1]);
axis([minx-1 maxx+1 miny-1 maxy+1]);
axis off;
hold on; %hold to add new axes
axes('Color','none'); %specify no background, else default is here white
axis([minx-1 maxx+1 miny-1 maxy+1]);
grid on;
box on;
set(gca,'XTick', minx-1:2:maxx+1);
%compute x tick labels
xticks = num2str(minx-1:2:maxx+1);
xticks = regexprep(regexprep(xticks,'-([\d.]+)','$1W'), '\b[\d\.]+','$0E');
xticks_cell = cellstr(regexp(xticks,'\s+','split'));
set(gca,'XTickLabel',xticks_cell)
set(gca,'YTick', miny-1:2:maxy+1);
% compute y tick labels
yticks = num2str(miny-1:2:maxy+1);
yticks = regexprep(regexprep(yticks,'-([\d.]+)','$1S'), '\b[\d\.]+','$0N');
yticks_cell = cellstr(regexp(yticks,'\s+','split'));
set(gca,'YTickLabel',yticks_cell)
```